# Ability to use XML and Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a android layout in xml, and I have an image i placed using java/android code. I have placed the image without using xml, but I was wondering if I am able to also use XML to position buttons on the page as well. I don't know how to do this because I am already using setcontentview to draw my image to the screen... and if I use setcontentview(R.exampleXMLfile) it will overwrite my image. Does anyone know a solution or example for this? The reason I am looking is because its a pain to add a button without using XML and eventually I want to have animations on the screen. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImageView in your xml file,

```
<ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/my_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
        />
```

or just View and set Background, or set background on any Layout in your xml.

```
<View
            android:id = "@+id/my_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image"

            />
```

Comment: That adds the image through the XML file which is cool. But eventually I want to add animations and i need java to do that. So I want to know if there is a way so that I can have a xml layout with buttons and be able to add pictures/graphics/animations on top of that?

Comment: Wrap your main layout in frame layout and set id to frame layout in main xml then find it by id, inflate another layout xml with layouf inflater or create programmatically and add it with FrameLayout.addview on top of it.